# How can I show the following in summation notation to help me find the limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to put $a_{1} = 3$, $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_{n}}$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$ into summation notation so I can show that the sequence has a limit (and subsequently find it). How would I go about doing this?

Should I try doing anything with logarithms?

Comment: What do you want to sum???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a_1=3$$

$$a_2=3^{1/2}$$

$$a_3=3^{1/4}$$
$$a_n=3^{1/{2^{n-1}}}$$

Note that $$1/{2^{n-1}}\to 0$$ therefore,

The limit is $$\lim_{n\to \infty }3^{1/{2^{n-1}}}=3^0=1$$

Comment: Is there a better formal way to prove this limit?

Comment: yes, you may say that the function $f(x)=3^x$ is continuous and as $x\to 0$ the function approaches the value of $3^0 =1.$

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a summation. Logorithms can make it nicer: $b_n:=\ln(a_n)$, so that $b_{n+1}= \frac{1}{2}b_n$, giving $b_n=(1/2)^{n-1}b_1$, or $a_n=a_1^{(1/2)^{n-1}}$.

Answer (score 0):

you can write the sum as $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 3^{\frac {1}{2^{i-1}}}$